# Facebook UI dialog for sending is changing the link after it is sent

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I try to send an invitation Via facebook graph API. The link contains an invitation code and everytime i send it with the Facebook UI dialog the link is changing.

```
FB.init({
  appId: 'facebook_app_id',
  status: true,
  cookie: true,
  xfbml: true
});

FB.ui({
  method: 'send',
  link: 'https://mywebsite.com/i/jywk2j',
  name: 'You get an invitation',
  to: 1
});
```

When I check the message, the link is 'https://mywebsite.com' and the '/i/jywk2f' is missing.

https://mywebsite.com/i/jywk2j Doesnt have any redirections or weird status codes or anything. It is just a normal landing page.

Somebody has any idea what im doing wrong here?

UPDATE

**App configuration**

```
Display name: My website name
Namespace: empty
App domains: empty
Hosting url: You have not generated a URL through one of our partners (Get one)
```

Select how your app integrates with Facebook

```
Only option selected: Website with Facebook Login
With url: https://mywebsite.com
```

**Results of https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug**

```
Response Code   200
Fetched URL     https://mywebsite.com/i/jywk2j
Canonical URL   https://mywebsite.com/i/jywk2j
```

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Tiny og:image       All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.
```

Object Properties

```
og:url      https://mywebsite.com/i/jywk2j
og:type     website
og:title    Title of my website
```

Comment: maybe you force redirect url in app configuration?

Comment: Could you run the link in the [Debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and get back to us with results?

Comment: I have indeed added this feature in Facebook apps. `Website with Facebook Login` to my domain Site url.

Comment: @ifaour Response 200, Fetched URL and Canonical URL are the right one. Some warnings that og meta tags are missing but I deleted them temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i fixed the problem. Thanks @chumkiu for pointing me in the right direction.

The problem was that i use a subdomain and my facebook application configuration was wrong. I needed to add `App Domains` with `mywebsite.com` and had to delete the subdomain in the `Website with Facebook Login` section